# How to hide table rows when there is no value

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Currently I have this list of table, whith total of 10 row and each row have those field in the figure. The value of each field I get from different existing documents. *(Figure only show 4)

[image: one]

When the table is display in another document, it will only display table rows with a value like below while for field with no value, the table rows will be blank. I also will able to edit this document.

[image]

So my problem now is when I want to print this document, the empty table row take so much spaces. I try to hide using hide when but it only hide the field but not rows.

My question, is there any way that I can hide table rows if there is no value in the row so that when I print the document, the empty row will hide? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the according hide- when formula to every row of your table:

- Mark the first row
- go to Properties
- open "Hide- Tab"
- set checkmark for Hide- Formula
- enter formula:
  Wasset1 = "" & WBrand1 = "" & WType1 = "" & WSerialNo1 = ""
- repeat for every row and change the numbers...

If you don't want to change 4 numbers for every row (can be cumbersome) then you could rewrite the hidewhen like this:

```
_nr := "1";
@GetField("Wasset" + _nr ) = "" & @GetField("WBrand" + _nr ) = "" &
@GetField("WType" + _nr ) = "" & @GetField("WSerialNo" + _nr )
```

now you can select all rows, paste the above formula, and then select the second, third, ... row subsequently and just change the number in the _nr- Line...

Comment: I already highlight first row, and open properties box but no Hide-When tab. I can't find the Hide-When tab.

Comment: The properties I should opened whether table properties or text properties?

Comment: Text properties... there is no hide when tab in table properties

Comment: Okay will try. I will get back to you later.